# How to interpret the results of linearHypothesis function when comparing regression coefficients?

Tags: r, regression

I used `linearHypothesis` function in order to test whether two regression coefficients are significantly different. Do you have any idea how to interpret these results?

Here is my output:

```
linearHypothesis(fit4.beta, "bfi2.e = bfi2.a")
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
bfi2.e - bfi2.a = 0

**Model 1:** restricted model<br />
**Model 2:** `mod.ipip.hexaco ~ bfi2.e + bfi2.n + bfi2.a + bfi2.o + bfi2.c`

    Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
    1    722 302.27                                  
    2    721 264.06  1    38.214 104.34 < 2.2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: `Pr(>F)` is the p-value of the test, and this is the output of interest. You want the interpretation of every output ?

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

Your F statistic is 104.34 and its p-value 2.2e-16.
The corresponding p-value suggests that we can reject the null hypothesis that both coefficients cancel each other at any level of significance commonly used in practice.

Were your p-value greater than 0.05, it is accustomed that you would not reject the null hypothesis.

**Long Answer**

The `linearHypothesis` function tests whether the difference between the coefficients is significant. In your example, whether the two betas cancel each other out β1 − β2 = 0.

Linear hypothesis tests are performed using F-statistics.
They compare your estimated model against a restrictive model which requires your hypothesis (restriction) to be true.

An alternative linear hypothesis testing would be to test whether β1 or β2 are nonzero, so we jointly test the hypothesis β1=0 and β2 = 0 rather than testing each one at a time. Here the null is rejected when one is rejected. Rejection here means that at least one of your hypotheses can be rejected. In other words  provide both linear restrictions to be tested as strings

Here are few examples of the multitude of ways you can test hypothese:

```
library(car)
data(mtcars)

model <- lm(mpg ~ hp + disp + am + wt, data = mtcars)
```

**You can test a linear combination of coeffecients**

```
linearHypothesis(model, c('hp + disp = 0'))

 Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
hp  + disp = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: mpg ~ hp + disp + am + wt

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq     F   Pr(>F)   
1     28 267.93                               
2     27 179.91  1    88.023 13.21 0.001154 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**joint probability**

```
linearHypothesis(model, c('hp = 0','disp = 0'))

Linear hypothesis test
        
    Hypothesis:
    hp = 0
    disp = 0
    
    Model 1: restricted model
    Model 2: mpg ~ hp + disp + am + wt
    
      Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)   
    1     29 278.32                                
    2     27 179.91  2    98.412 7.3847 0.002766 **
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the t statistics, which test for the predictive power of each variable in
the presence of all the others, another test which can be used is the F-test. (this is the F-test that you would get at the bottom of a linear model)

This tests the null hypothesis that all of the β’s are equal to zero against
the alternative that allows them to take any values. If we reject this null hypothesis
(which we do because the p-value is small), then this is the same as saying there
is enough evidence to conclude that at least one of the covariates has predictive
power in our linear model, i.e. that using a regression is predictively ‘better’ than
just guessing the average.

So basically, you are testing whether all coefficients are different from zero or some other arbitrary linear hypothesis, as opposed to a t-test where you are testing individual coefficients.

Answer (score -1):

The answer given above is detailed enough except that for this test we are more interested in the two variables hence the linear hypothesis does not investigate the null hypothesis that all of the β’s are equal to zero against the alternative that allows them to take any values but just for two variables of interest which makes this test equivalent to a t-test.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).